# How to find an open file handle by path in Python?

Tags: python, process

Let's say my program discovered that it can't delete a file because it's opened in the same process.

How can I get the file handle by knowing only the path?

(Please don't suggest how to close files properly -- I need this for checking my students' work automatically)

Comment: Ask the operating system.